# Best practice to handle expensive, view-specific objects in MVVM

Tags: android, architecture, android-architecture-components

So MVVM states clearly that view models shouldn't contain view implementation/view specific objects. However, some views need objects that are either expensive to instantiate (e.g. a map rendering object), or take up a lot of memory. On Android, the temptation is to put these objects into a `ViewModel` so they survive lifecycle changes. But this breaks MVVM principles.

Is there any good practice how to handle heavy, view-specific objects in MVVM?

Answer (score 1):

As you just said, view model should not contains any view reference due to detached-view reference dangerous event.
Any *heavy views* should be instantiated into lifecycle owner class too. If this slow down view rendering, you can always apply some post-create or async logic.

View model can help you in this way. Infact, you can observe to a mutable flag object on viewmodel from the view. When the *lock* flag change you start the *heavy object* rendering.

This is just an example, maybe if you can be more specific on what you meant with *heavy view objects* we can find out a more precise and efficent solution.

Comment: Please note that I wasn't referring to views / Android `View` objects themselves, but rather dependencies of these objects. E.g. like a map renderer that would be bound to some `MapView` (not necessarily the Google implementation, more generally speaking). I made the title a bit more specific.

Comment: Objects that aren't properly views (like a renderer) can be managed directly in viewmodel if they aren't strictly bounded to the view itself. Then the view update must be triggered throght observers

Comment: Can they, according to the MVVM definition? Wouldn't they be considered view implementation? - For example, a map object might be responsible for things like marker rendering, clustering, etc.

Comment: They would not. The MVVM definition says that we have to avoid to keep view reference on objects that aren't lifecycle owners. Suddenly in that way some logics could broke due to unexpected view detach (or lifecycle state change). But if we keep some non-view object that are not bound to a view and if we can manually manage view update (thrught observers) then we are respecting the MVVM definition and we are working in a lifecycle safe mode.

Comment: Of course a map object responsibile of marker rendering is strictly bound to view and then must be managed in a lifecycle owner class

Comment: I think you need to get straight what can't got into ViewModel. Anything that is bound to lifecycle owner shouldn't be in ViewModel.